# PHP - Unexpected else

Tags: php, if-statement

Can anyone tell me why PHP is igving me this error?:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\registration.php on line 139
```

(error is the one in *** since I didn't output all the code)

I can't seem to find the problem

Code:

```
<?php

if ($isLoggedin === false) {

                                include("form.php");


                                    if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {

                                        // DECLARE VARIABLES TO NULL
                                        $Name = null; $Surname = null; $Username = null; $Email = null; $C_Email = null; $Password = null; $C_Password = null; $SecQ = null; $SecA = null;

                                        // GET ELEMENTS FROM BROWSER POST.
                                        if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
                                            $Name = $_POST['Name'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['Surname'])) {
                                            $Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
                                            $Username = $_POST['Username'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {
                                            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['C_Email'])) {
                                            $C_Email = $_POST['C_Email'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
                                            $Password = $_POST['password'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['c_password'])) {
                                            $C_Password = $_POST['c_password'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['SecQ'])) {
                                            $SecQ = $_POST['SecQ'];
                                        }
                                        if (isset($_POST['SecA'])) {
                                            $SecA = $_POST['SecA'];
                                        }

                                        // CONNECT TO MYSQL DB
                                        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'storefileuser', 'storefileuser');
                                        mysql_select_db ("storefile");


                                        if (!$con) {

                                                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                            } else {

                                                if ($Name == null || $Surname== null || $Password == null || $C_Password == null || $Email == null || $C_Email == null || $SecQ == null || $SecA == null ) {
                                                    echo "Missing details. Please enter all fields.";
                                                } else {

                                                    $usernameexists = false;
                                                    $emailexists = false;
                                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$Username'");
                                                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                                        $usernameexists = true;
                                                    }
                                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$Email'");
                                                    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                                        $emailexists = true;
                                                    }

                                                    if (!$emailexists || !$usernameexists) { 
                                                        // VALIDATE CONFIRMS
                                                        if  ($Email == $C_Email && $Password == $C_Password) {

                                                            $encrypt_password=md5($Password);

                                                            $query = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Name,Surname, Password, Email, SecQ, SecA) VALUES ('".$Username."', '".$Name."', '".$Surname."', '".$encrypt_password."', '".$SecQ."', '".$SecA."', '".$Email."')";


                                                            echo "You have been successfully registered.";


                                                            }

                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error registering.";


                                                    } else {
                                                        echo "Username or email already entered in the database!";
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        }

                                    } 






    }   else {

            echo '<h1> You are already registered/logged in!</h1>';


            }                               
?>
```

Comment: There isn't 139 lines in your code provided.

Comment: Looks like there is an extra `}` just before the `} else { echo "error registering"`.

Comment: ... that closes the `if ($Email ==...)` and the subsequent one closes the `if (!$emailexists...)` too early.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It still gives me the same error if I remove it (unexpected else)

Comment: OP, can you post nicer code? This is hard to read on SO :(

Comment: has nothing to do with your error, but you NEVER should use  things like this `('".$Username."', '".$Name."', '".$Surname."', '".$encrypt_password."', '".$SecQ."', '".$SecA."', '".$Email."')"` if you get this variables directly from user input. Because this is vulnerable for SQL injections.

Comment: No wonder you can't find the problem; that formatting is pretty bad. Format your code more neatly and problems like this will be much easier to solve.

Comment: In your first if clause posted here, you have an echo string defined over multiple lines. you can define a multiline string using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), but not simply by breaking the lines. the php error is misleading.

Comment: @Mansfield I don't know, whenever I copy and paste from Notepad++ all the indentation gets mixed up. http://pastebin.com/6tCtqrJ3

Comment: Formatting your code or using an IDE with at least a syntax validator will help prevent such trivial errors.

Comment: @Brian I copied your code with that extra `}` removed and it lints just fine with no syntax error.

Comment: Although not directly answering your question, you should maybe rethink your if/else statements.. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php would be a nice alternative, either that or move most of your checks into functions and give returns, or you could switch/break.. there are a few neater ways of doing what you're trying to..

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's not working for me :/

Comment: Any time you see an error like that, start looking for an extra or missing bracket, or an extra or missing semi colon. Related, you'll sometimes see "unexpected end in x" where "x" is the last line in the script. That also usually means a missing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo "You have been successfully registered.";

'}'

} else {
    echo "Error registering.";
}
```

That's the problem. The bracket I put in quotes.

I strongly advise you to use a IDE designed for PHP (like Eclipse PDT for example). It will show you exactly were the problem is with your syntax.

Comment: I still get the same problem. I'm using Notepad++.

Comment: Try also to format the code well - it will also help identify the place where something is wrong. Are you sure the changes got saved? This is the only place where you have additional bracket, unless there is something you haven't posted here.

Comment: You removed the wrong bracket - the one after "Error registering" and it should the one after "you have been successfully registered."

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra closing curly brace just before the `} else {` for your big if statement (You know which one I'm talking about)

And:

A few lines befores 139, there is a **missing** curly brace.

```
    } else {
        echo "Error registering.";
    } // here is where it should be.                            
} else {
    echo "Username or email already entered in the database!";
}
```

Working code:
http://pastebin.com/NcL85pnu

Comment: It still gives me the unexpected Else error

Comment: Please format your code using a better IDE. Notepad++ I've only ever had bad experience with. You should consider Sublime Text 2 - and *why* is there so many blank lines and extra lines?

Comment: Please read updated answer.